# Xpath in selenium basic: click on an href nested in <ul><li>

Tags: html, css, selenium, xpath

with Selenium Basic I tried to click on the element 'MyLocalLang' nested in `<li>` tags.
The source is:

```
<div id="navBar" class="NavBar">
<nav id="navMenu" class="Wrapper"> == 40
    <ul class="navMenuUL">
        <li> ... </li>
        <li> ... </li>
        <li> ... </li>
        <li> ... </li>
        <li> ... </li>
        <li> ... </li>
        <li> ... </li>
        <li> ... </li>
        <li> 
            <a class="nav" href="//en.mysite.com/item/">MyLocalLang</a>
        </li>
        <li> ... </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I must select only that exposes `<li>` tag: the other tags contains useless informations.
The code `driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='navMenu']/ul/li[9]/a")` works well, but:

- Not always MyLocalLang is the nineth element of the bar;
- MyLocalLang name link string could be in any other languages, so MaLangueLocale, MiaLinguaLocale, MiIdiomaLocal, etc.;
- the url could be in many other languages, so could be fr.mysite.com, it.mysite.com, en.mysite.com, etc.
- the @class 'nav' is not useful, because exists in every `<li>` tags.

My attempts didn't work.
I tried:

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='navMenu']/ul/li[contains(@href,'*mysite.com/item/')]/a").Click
```

with or without final `/a`, and many others.

Can anyone help me to make the right xpath expression, and click on that link, no matters the local language is or its position in the list, please? Note that I'm using selenium in a VBA project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to change the HTML?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `href` attribute is in the `<a>` tag, not the `<li>` tag. Try

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='navMenu']/ul/li/a[contains(@href, 'mysite.com/item/')]").Click()
```

You should also remove the `*` from the `href` value, it will be considered as part of the string to search.

Comment: Thanks, Andersson and Guy. This code works like a charm! A little edit, in VBA only ".Click", without final parenthesis ().

Answer (score 0):

`href` is attribute of anchor not `li`, so try

```
//li/a[contains(@href,'mysite.com/item/')]
```

Answer (score 0):

First get all li elements and keep them on a WebElement list. Then get the element using it's tagName in the loop.

Try to use css selector like below:

```
List<WebElement> allLiElems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#navMenu > ul > li"));
for (WebElement elem : allLiElems) {
    String link = elem.findElement(By.tagName("a")).getAttribute("href");
    if(link.contains("mysite.com")){
        elem.findElement(By.tagName("a")).click();
    }           
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't know java language. But your answer is interesting because less subsceptible to future changes in Html source. Seleniumbasic don't use java: it's for VB.Net, VBA and VBScript.I know, it is no more updated (I will use this code in an Excel macro). Maybe, it could be useful in the future. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @Marco Thanks, no problem. You can take help from it. If you send some portion of code where you are using I can translate this in your language.